# Auth0 Laravel OIDC invalid_request profile is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, openid-connect, auth0

I'm testing a laravel application with Auth0 OIDC security. I've followed the tutorial [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/laravel/01-login) to the letter.

In my Auth0 account I created a new Enterprise / OIDC connection, and used the auto-discover feature to pull in the endpoints from the OIDC server. My scope is `openid profile email`, which is default.

Clicking the "play" button in the OIDC definition page in Auth0 takes me to the test login at the OIDC provider's page, and the test returns successfully with the user profile report in Auth0 looking correct.

When I click the `login` link in my laravel app, it goes to Auth0 as expected which opens the OIDC flow into the provider, and I can login with my credentials. On the return trip from Auth0 into my app however the callback URL is

```
https://mytestapp.test/auth0/callback?error=invalid_request&error_description=profile%20is%20not%20defined&state=7c130bc30c3f5b9d2d9c3bcb1ff18bf6
```

which then triggers an error of

```
Argument 1 passed to Auth0\Login\Repository\Auth0UserRepository::getUserByUserInfo() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Users/myuser/Code/mytestapp/vendor/auth0/login/src/controllers/Auth0Controller.php on line 37
```

Where is the "profile is not defined" error coming from, and how can I debug to see exactly what Auth0 is getting back from the OIDC provider?

Comment: Maybe you can debug further by editing your auth0 conf file setting `'guzzle_options' => ['debug' => true]` to track all the requests and response from your app 

Comment: Can we see how you create the initial login request to auth0?